# Get image title and description attributes in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have looked up all the web but nothing worked out for me. What i am trying to do is get the attached image's title and description which you give in media library where you also have caption, alt text and description. i want that title to show in title attribute in html like so:

```
<a href="http://somelink.com/" title="here i want to fetch that title">
```

**Edit:**
Keep in mind i am trying to output a gallery shortcode in a page here.

**Edit:**
Here is the full output of shortcode in visual composer

```
public function vc_gallery_html( $atts, $content = null) {        

        //Get and extract shortcode attributes
        $atts = vc_map_get_attributes( 'vc_gallery', $atts);
        extract( $atts );

        //Design options
        $wrapper_classes = apply_filters( VC_SHORTCODE_CUSTOM_CSS_FILTER_TAG, vc_shortcode_custom_css_class( $css, ' ' ), 'vc_gallery', $atts );

        if (!empty($gallery_duration)) {
            $gallery_duration_html = $gallery_duration;
        }else{
            $gallery_duration_html = '600';
        }

        if (!empty($gallery_delay)) {
            $gallery_delay_html = $gallery_delay;
        }else{
            $gallery_delay_html = '0';
        }

        if ($gallery_spacing == '0px') {
            $parent_margin_css = '0px';
            $child_padding_css = '0px';
        }
        if ($gallery_spacing == '5px') {
            $parent_margin_css = '-2.5px';
            $child_padding_css = '2.5px';
        }
        if ($gallery_spacing == '10px') {
            $parent_margin_css = '-5px';
            $child_padding_css = '5px';
        }
        if ($gallery_spacing == '15px') {
            $parent_margin_css = '-7.5px';
            $child_padding_css = '7.5px';
        }
        if ($gallery_spacing == '30px') {
            $parent_margin_css = '-15px';
            $child_padding_css = '15px';
        }
        if ($gallery_spacing == '50px') {
            $parent_margin_css = '-25px';
            $child_padding_css = '25px';
        }

        if ($gallery_masonry == 'yes') {
            $gallery_masonry_class = 'masonry';
        }else{
            $gallery_masonry_class = '';
        }

        $html = '';

        if ($gallery_lightbox == 'yes') {
        }

        $html .= '
            <div class="sp-gallery ' . $gallery_columns . ' '. $wrapper_classes .' '. $gallery_masonry_class .'" data-aos="'. $gallery_animation .'" data-aos-delay="'. $gallery_delay_html .'" data-aos-duration="'. $gallery_duration_html .'" data-aos-once="true" style="margin: '. $parent_margin_css .';">';

            $gallery_images_array = explode(',', $gallery_images);

            foreach ($gallery_images_array as $image_id) {

                if ($gallery_columns == 'column1') {
                    $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $image_id ); //get img URL   
                    $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 1100, 1100, true, true, true ); //resize & crop img
                }
                if ($gallery_columns == 'column2') {
                    $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $image_id ); //get img URL   
                    $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 750, 750, true, true, true ); //resize & crop img
                }
                if ($gallery_columns == 'column3') {
                    $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $image_id ); //get img URL   
                    $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 570, 570, true, true, true ); //resize & crop img
                }
                if ($gallery_columns == 'column4') {
                    $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $image_id ); //get img URL   
                    $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 475, 475, true, true, true ); //resize & crop img
                }
                if ($gallery_columns == 'column5') {
                    $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $image_id ); //get img URL   
                    $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 320, 320, true, true, true ); //resize & crop img
                }
                if ($gallery_columns == 'column6') {
                    $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $image_id ); //get img URL   
                    $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 285, 285, true, true, true ); //resize & crop img
                }
                if ($gallery_masonry == 'yes') {
                    $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $image_id ); //get img URL   
                    $image = $img_url;
                }

                $thumb_img = get_post( get_post_thumbnail_id() );

                $html .= '<a href="'. $img_url .'" class="gallery-item" style="padding: '. $child_padding_css .';" title="'. $thumb_img->post_content .'">';
                    $html .= '<img src="' . $image . '" style="border-radius: '. $gallery_radius .';">';
                $html .= '</a>';
            }

        $html .= '</div>'
        ;

        return $html;

    } 

}
```

Comment: Is that a page? Does it contains many posts?  the logic is like this -> 

`<a href="http://somelink.com/" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">`

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos yes its a page and i an trying to output a gallery shortcode. here the_title() pulls the title of the page but i want the title of media attachment.

Comment: what is your code to get the image itself?

Comment: if you have the attachment_id you should be able to do `$att_title = get_the_title($attach_id)`. Will you refactor your code or is this it? You are repeating yourself a lot.

Comment: @RST well this is it, it worked perfectly for title.